# Prolog: добавление элемента в конец списка

Tags: список, prolog

Я конечно понимаю, вопрос банальный, но у меня все-равно не получается добавить элемент в конец списка, хоть убейся лбом об стену!

такие правила как эти:

```
add([],E,[E]).
add([H|T1],E,[H|T2]):-add(T1,E,T2).
```

не работают...

В общем я запарился, устал и начал писать уже всякий бред лишь бы сработало, но...

```
DOMAINS
list=integer*

PREDICATES
insert(list,integer,list)
add(integer,integer)
CLAUSES
insert([],N,T):-!,T=[H|G],add(N,H).
insert([H|T],N,[H|T1]):-insert(T,N,T1).
add(N,H):-H=N.
GOAL
insert(T,2,T),insert(T,3,T),write(T)
```

Ничего не выходит T_T

Comment: На SWI-Prolog первоначальные правила работают. В приведенном ниже коде не разбирался, единственный вопрос, есть ли в конце точка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
include "test.inc"
domains
list=integer*
predicates
  test(list,integer,list)-(i,i,o)
clauses
test([],E,[E])
test([L1|H1],E,[L1|H2]):-test(H1,E,H2).
goal
  test([5,4,3,2], 1,  X), write(X).
```

Answer (score 1):

```
domains
  l=integer*
predicftes
  add(integer,l,l)
clauses
  add(E,[],[E]).
  add(E,[H|T],[H|T1]):-add(E,T,T1).
goal
  write("Введите добавляемый элемент: "),
  readint(E),
  add(E,[1,2,3],L),
  write("L=",L).
```

Comment: @shura, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.